# Selecting model with where clause involving joined table with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

**projects** `== has_many ==>` **project_stages** `<== has_many ==` **stages**

I am trying to select those projects where stage.name = 'completed', so I thought one of the following would work:

```rb
Project.joins(:stages).where(stages: { name: 'completed' })
Project.where(stage: Stage.find_by(name: 'completed'))
```

No dice.

---

**Models:**

```rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :project_stages
  has_many :stages, through: :project_stages
  ...
end
```

```rb
class ProjectStage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :stage
end
```

```rb
class Stage < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_stages
end
```

Comment: `Project.joins(project_stages: :stages).where(stages: { name: 'completed' }).distinct` should work for you although depending on how you intend to use this data `Project.includes(:project_stages).where(project_stages: {stage_id: Stages.find_by_name('complete').id})` might be more efficient

Comment: Gives me this error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'ProjectStage' to association named 'stages'; perhaps you misspelled it?` (same for both)

Comment: What SQL query is being generated from that first line you tried?

Comment: @Daniel the reason you got the error to what @engineersmnky posted is bcs there is a slight error in that stages is pluralized in the `joins` method when it shouldn't be. This will work: `Project.joins(project_stages: :stage).where(stages: {name: 'completed'})`

Comment: Nailed it! Works flawlessly. Would you happen to have a resource on this you might recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I think `scopes` are a good fit for this:

```rb
scope :search_by_stages, ->(param){
    joins(:stages).where(Stage.arel_table[:name].lower.eq(param.downcase))
  }
```

You can add the `scope` defined above within your `Project` model, where `param` is the name (that search is case insensitive, you can remove the `lower` and the `downcase` if you want it case sensitive).

You can use it like this (in case you are not familiar with scopes): `Project.search_by_stages('name')`

Hope the above helps!